# SQL to find the employee leave days within the months

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I want to display the employee leaves from the table when i choose the start date=2017-02-01 and leave date=2017-02-28. The output are displaying like that

```
EmployeeID Leave_Start_Date Leave_End-Date
--------- ----------------- ---------------
1         2017-01-29        2017-02-01
2         2017-02-01        2017-02-02
```

I want the output to like that

```
EmployeeID Leave_Start_Date Leave_End-Date
--------- ----------------- ---------------
1         2017-02-01        2017-02-01
2         2017-02-01        2017-02-02
```

I write the query like that

```
DECLARE @StartDate  DATE
,       @EndDate    DATE            
SET     @StartDate='2017-02-01'
SET     @EndDate='2017-02-28'
SELECT      *
FROM        Employee_Leave
WHERE       Leave_Start_Date BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
OR          Leave_End_Date  BETWEEN @StartDate  AND @EndDate
ORDER BY    Leave_Start_Date;
```

Comment: You also want to truncate the `start` - `end` intervals?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following query:

```
DECLARE @StartDate  DATE
,       @EndDate    DATE            
SET     @StartDate='2017-02-01'
SET     @EndDate='2017-02-28'

SELECT      EmployeeID,
            CASE 
               WHEN Leave_Start_Date < @StartDate THEN @StartDate
               ELSE Leave_Start_Date 
            END AS Leave_Start_Date,
            CASE 
               WHEN Leave_End_Date > @EndDate THEN @EndDate
               ELSE Leave_End_Date 
            END AS Leave_End_Date          
FROM        Employee_Leave 
WHERE       Leave_Start_Date <= @EndDate AND
            Leave_End_Date >= @StartDate
ORDER BY    Leave_Start_Date;
```

The query truncates `[Leave_Start_Date, Leave_End_Date]` interval to match `[@StartDate, @EndDate]` interval.

[**Demo here**](http://rextester.com/LCI11039)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `>=` and `<=` operators, and cast(column name) to date format

Example below :

```
SELECT * FROM sys.sys_config where cast(set_time as date) <= "2016-09-25" and cast(set_time as date) >= "2016-09-01"
```